# How to change a buttons property without clicking on it, ios

Tags: ios, uibutton

```
- (IBAction)heapsOfButtons:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    button.alpha = 0.25;

}
```

Let's say I use this action for ten buttons, now they're all with 0.25 alpha.

How do I change all of their alpha colour at once to 1?

Thanks.

Comment: Call `someButton.alpha = 1.0;` on all of the buttons. Your question is really vague. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @rmaddy They're all called button as you see, I am casting UIButton to sender. And this is a action click, executes when the "selected" button is clicked/pressed. Now my question is how do I change it without clicking a button.

Comment: FYI - you are casting `sender` to `UIButton`, not the other way around. And your buttons are not called `button`. That's simply the name of a local variable being used in the method you posted.

Comment: It sounds like you are a a complete beginner to iOS. I strongly recommend you work through a tutorial - look into the iTunes course called `Programming iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad`. This Stanford course will teach how to build a complete app. Alternatively, look into: http://raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, set up all the buttons as a `UICollectionView` object -- you can do that in a Storyboard or programatically.

Second, use a method that's activated by some event to change the property of the entire `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

You have outlet properties for each of your buttons, right? Do:

```
self.someButtonOutlet.alpha = 1.0;
```

where `someButtonOutlet` is replaced by an actual button property name. Repeat this for each property.

Comment: +1. Another option could be to declare an IBOutletCollection containing all of the UIButtons. Then, iterate through the collection and set the alpha = 1.

Comment: Of course. But the OP was terribly vague about they have.